# Android Map View in AVD

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm busy with adding a Map View in my android application. I'm trying to get this running on my AVD but I can't get this to work.

I'm following this tutorial: [click here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). I have to install the Google APIs add-on, so I used the Android SDK Manager to find the add on, but it's not there?

What to do??

Comment: Could you post some code or error messages you receive in logcat? Or at least the behaviour of your app?

Comment: Console says this:

[2011-11-13 16:12:23 - **] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2011-11-13 16:12:23 - **] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-11-13 16:12:23 - **] Launch canceled!

Comment: can you post the logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the key in your layout XML (where you have the mapview) that you had to generate from your debug keystore to get the map image to show up? If not, you'll need to do that and you'll need to generate another version to work with your final (non debug) keystore for when you package the .apk.

Here are the instructions from google: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: Hello,

Yes I've did that. Problem is this:I have to select "Google APIs by Google Inc." as build target but I can't find that target there? How can I add that build target to the list?